# Error character when post data in php?

Tags: php

I have a sample data: [image: image1]

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value="3602s，5300,5300XM，6126,6131，6131 NFC,6133,"  />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>
```

index.php

```
if($_POST['name']){
   echo $_POST['name'];
}
```

When I echo $_POST['name'] the result is:

[image: image2]

How do I fix this error ?

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue, but i'm not sure

Comment: Where is your data coming from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your data, you have `，`, this is not a normal comma (`,`) character.

This is actually ASCII 239 followed by ASCII 188 and ASCII 140 (not sure why it counts as 3 characters), not ASCII 44 (normal comma).

To replace this, you can try:

```
$_POST['name'] = str_replace(chr(239).chr(188).chr(140), ',', $_POST['name']);
```

Example: http://codepad.org/6xkIFBDL

Comment: Yay, i was right too, it's an encoding issue, just didn'T see it at first

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame: In the `$_POST` result, I saw the "box" character after the `s`, the `XM` and the `31`,  I looked at the string, and saw that the comma looked odd,  I highlighted it and noticed it was different (there was a weird space after it). :-P

Comment: @Rocket: result is [Error!][error]  [error]: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/528/capturenyz.png/

Comment: @HaiTruong: What's the result?

Comment: @HaiTruong: Cool.  Glad I could help :-D